# Windows expecting return value from Python

Tags: windows, python-2.7, batch-file, cmd

I have a Windows script that runs a Python script which returns some value.  How do I get the return value/string from the Python script in my Windows script?

```
**script1.py**
......
return something


**dosbatch.bat**
......
python script1.py
......
```

Comment: You cannot use `return` outside a function.

Answer (score 2):

Bare use of `return` without declaring a function in not allowed in a Python script. So, that will throw an error.

However, you can use the `print` function to get the output on your console.

But again, this will not be similar to a `return` value, so you'd not be able to store it into a variable.

As it is further mentioned that a value is being returned from a function, you can do this

```
for /f %%i in ('python script1.py') do set VAR=%%i
```

This will store the value in the variable `VAR`.

However make sure you do call the function upon running it as a script. This can be done by writing `func()` inside `if __name__=='__main__':` clause, where `func()` returns your desired value.

Comment: My python script is a function that returns a value.  Is there anyway to get the return value into a DOS variable?

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I'm updating my answer

Comment: I am not receiving any returned value from my function.  If I run a python script calling the python function script, it works, but when I try from a DOS batch, it returns nothing.

Comment: If you have `python script.py` in your batch file, it will not trigger the function inside the module which returns your expected value.

Answer (score 0):

`%errorlevel%` contains a processes exit code.

The best way to use is this

```
If errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 echo program returned 1
If errorlevel 2 if not errorlevel 3 echo program returned 2
```